# How to get a value from the closest <td> with a specific class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

Im using [Jeditable](http://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jeditable&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable&ei=QT9GT7_kG8vT4QTa-bWvDg&usg=AFQjCNE-JyYtGVoT4sooIMJxDiE5rhHsCA&sig2=50h-DlaoXQWgcV666-HijA) inside a table, to update a value.

```
function updateOwner(row, value, settings) {

            var td = $(row).closest('.cvrnummer');

            alert(td.html());

            $.post('UserAdministration/UpdateOwners', { owner: value }, function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        }

        $('.editable').editable(function (value, settings) {
            updateOwner(this, value, settings);
            return (value);
        }, {
            data: " {'mona':'moma','cecilie':'cecilie','jacob':'jacob', 'morten':'morten', 'rasmus' : 'rasmus', 'selected':'mona'}",
            type: 'select',
            submit: 'OK'
        });
```

The table looks like this:

```
<table id="userTable" class="table-autofilter table-autosort" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>CVR-Nummer</th>
<th>Firma navn</th>
<th class="table-filterable">Tilhører</th>
<th class="table-sortable:date">Oprettet</th>
<th>Sidst online</th>
<th></th>
<th class="table-sortable:numeric table-sortable">Besvaret (%)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
       <td class="cvrnummer"></td>
       <td></td>
       <td class="editable" style="text-align: center;"></td>
       <td></td>   
       <td></td>
       <td>Se besvarelser</td>
       <td>
       </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to pass the value inside

```
<td class="cvrnummer"></td>
```

when i use AJAX to post a value, but im not sure how to get the value. Im using:

```
var td = $(row).closest('.cvrnummer');

            alert(td.html());
```

which is returning null.

How do i get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do

```
var td = $(row).closest('tr').find('td.cvrnummer');
```

because `closest()` goes up the DOM tree, while `find()` goes down. You can't use `prev()` because it returns just the preovious element

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're selected the `<td class="editable">` as the first argument to the `updateOwner` method. The `closest` selector in jQuery will not look at the siblings to the selected `td`, it just goes up through the DOM. You could try `var td = $(row).siblings('.cvrnummer');` or `var td = $(row).parent().find('.cvrummer');`